# Intellij IDEA: как автоматически отформатировать код?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Предположим я написал java код и хочу чтобы IDEA сама расставила правильные отступы, переносы строк и т.д.

Я знаю где-то есть функция что можно выделить кусок кода и нажать ... что-то а что? помогите чайнику...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Выделите участок кода, который требуется отформатировать и нажмите:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (для Windows/Linux)
- <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (для Mac).

Comment: На маке оказалась cmd+alt+shift+L но когда ваш вариант попробовал идея мне сама предложила... Спасибо!

Comment: @Павел, Добавил в ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ дали выше, но для продуктивной разработки [перечень горячих клавиш для Intellij IDEA](http://devcolibri.com/2151) точно не будет лишним